# Generating $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$

Tags: list-manipulation, number-theory, group-theory

I'm using Mathematica to illustrate basic number theory concepts in a graduate cryptography class. To generate elements of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$, I can use the following code:

```
Z[n_] := Table[If[GCD[i, n] == 1, i, ## &[]], {i, n}];
```

Example:

```
In: Z[21]
Out: {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20}
```

The notation `## &[]` used in defining `Z[n_]` will certainly raise questions for students who have no prior exposure to Mathematica. Is there a simpler way of generating elements of $\mathbb{Z}^*_n$?

**PS:** I can use:

```
Z[n_] := DeleteCases[Table[If[GCD[i, n] == 1, i], {i, n}], Null];
```

but that's not elegant either.

Comment: How about a `Select` over a simple range?

Comment: `Z[n_] := Select[CoprimeQ[#, n] &]@Range[1, n]`

Comment: @evanb I just posted something very similar - simultaneously with your comment...

Comment: `Position[MultiplicativeOrder[21, #] & /@ Range@20, _?IntegerQ, 1]`

Comment: `Select[Range[21], NumericQ@MultiplicativeOrder[21, #] &]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simpler function instead of `GCD` that allows you to skip the comparison with `1`: [`CoprimeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoprimeQ.html). Using it, we can do this:

```
Z[n_] := With[{i = Range[n]}, Pick[i, CoprimeQ[i, n]]]

Z[21]

(* ==> {1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20} *)
```

Here I deliberately tried to avoid any cryptic symbols (although perhaps that should be par for the course in a cryptography class)...

**Edit speed**

Considering the comment, I looked at the timings and found that my solution is also about twice as fast as the ones posted by Mr. Wizard:

```
AbsoluteTiming@Do[
  Select[Range[n], CoprimeQ[#, n] &],
  {n, 200, 3000}]

(* ==> {3.102409, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming@Do[
  Join @@ Position[Range[n]/n, _[_, n]],
  {n, 200, 3000}]

(* ==> {3.367569, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming@Do[
  With[{i = Range[n]}, Pick[i, CoprimeQ[i, n]]],
  {n, 200, 3000}]

(* ==> {1.692815, Null} *)
```

The general rule is that you get more speed if you use the listability of built-in functions, instead of doing explicit looping (or `Table`, or `Map` operations). Listability here means that you can feed a whole List into the argument of `CoprimeQ`, and the looping will be done at a lower level internally.

Comment: Thanks. This is the simplest of all the suggestions. Out of curiosity, do you know which of the suggestions is the most efficient?

Comment: Without doing any testing, the general rule is that you get more speed if you use the listability of built-in functions, instead of doing explicit looping (or `Table`, or `Map` operations). Listability here means that you can feed a whole `List` into the argument of `CoprimeQ`, and the looping will be done at a lower level internally. That's why I think my solution will also be efficient: it works with lists as a whole, never breaking it up into its elements.

Comment: @Sadeq And that is exactly why I prefer Jens' solution. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah, it's very elegant in that it is both the simplest (IMHO) and the most efficient!

Answer (score 5):

I prefer Jens' solution but here is another simple formation:

```
z1[n_] := Select[Range[n], CoprimeQ[#, n] &]
```

And one for just for fun:

```
z2[n_] := Join @@ Position[Range[n]/n, _[_, n]]
```

Comment: That second one blew my mind a little bit! +1.